# Find all the unchecked checkboxes and highlight only unchecked checkboxes on button click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have multiple *checkboxes* and on button click I need to validate below cases

1. Check whether all the *checkboxes* are selected or not, if not highlight all
2. Check if any of the *checkboxes* is not selected and highlight it
3. If all are selected then go to next page.

The code is in ASP.NET MVC 3 and i am using jquery.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<span id="errorMsg1"  style="display: none; color: red; font-size: 25px;">*</span>
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckedStatus, new { id = "cbCheckedStatus1", name = "cbCheckedStatus" })
</td>
<td>Message1</td>
<tr>
tr>
<td>
<span id="errorMsg2"  style="display: none; color: red; font-size: 25px;">*</span>
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckedStatus, new { id = "cbCheckedStatus2", name = "cbCheckedStatus" })
</td>
<td>Message2</td>
<tr>
tr>
<td>
<span id="errorMsg3"  style="display: none; color: red; font-size: 25px;">*</span>
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckedStatus, new { id = "cbCheckedStatus3", name = "cbCheckedStatus" })
</td>
<td>Message3</td>
<tr>
tr>
<td>
<span id="errorMsg4"  style="display: none; color: red; font-size: 25px;">*</span>
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckedStatus, new { id = "cbCheckedStatus4", name = "cbCheckedStatus" })
</td>
<td>Message4</td>
<tr>
tr>
<td>
<span id="errorMsg5"  style="display: none; color: red; font-size: 25px;">*</span>
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckedStatus, new { id = "cbCheckedStatus5", name = "cbCheckedStatus" })
</td>
<td>Message5</td>
<tr>
tr>
<td>
<span id="errorMsg6"  style="display: none; color: red; font-size: 25px;">*</span>
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckedStatus, new { id = "cbCheckedStatus6", name = "cbCheckedStatus" })
</td>
<td>Message6</td>
<tr>
tr>
<td>
<span id="errorMsg7"  style="display: none; color: red; font-size: 25px;">*</span>
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckedStatus, new { id = "cbCheckedStatus7", name = "cbCheckedStatus" })
</td>
<td>Message7</td>
<tr>
</table>
```

My Jquery is below,

```
jQuery().ready(function domReady($) {
    $('#BtnAccept').click(function () {
    if ($('input:checkbox').length == $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').length) {
            $('#cbCheckedStatus1').addClass("outLineRed");
            $('#cbCheckedStatus2').addClass("outLineRed");
            $('#cbCheckedStatus3').addClass("outLineRed");
            $('#cbCheckedStatus4').addClass("outLineRed");
            $('#cbCheckedStatus5').addClass("outLineRed");
            $('#cbCheckedStatus6').addClass("outLineRed");
            $('#cbCheckedStatus7').addClass("outLineRed");   
            $('#errorMsg1').show();
            $('#errorMsg2').show();
            $('#errorMsg3').show();
            $('#errorMsg4').show();
            $('#errorMsg5').show();
            $('#errorMsg6').show();
            $('#errorMsg7').show();                    
            $('#errorMsg').show();
            $('#spMsgError').show();
            $('#spMsgError').html("Please confirm all the items above, and place a check mark in every box.");
            $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;");
            return false;
        }
        else if( write condition){
        //Find unchecked checkboxes and highlight it.
                 }
        else {
            $('#cbCheckedStatus1').addClass("outLineRed");
            $('#cbCheckedStatus2').addClass("outLineRed");
            $('#cbCheckedStatus3').addClass("outLineRed");
            $('#cbCheckedStatus4').addClass("outLineRed");
            $('#cbCheckedStatus5').addClass("outLineRed");
            $('#cbCheckedStatus6').addClass("outLineRed");
            $('#cbCheckedStatus7').addClass("outLineRed"); 
            $('#errorMsg1').hide();
            $('#errorMsg2').hide();
            $('#errorMsg3').hide();
            $('#errorMsg4').hide();
            $('#errorMsg5').hide();
            $('#errorMsg6').hide();
            $('#errorMsg7').hide();                   

            $('#errorMsg').hide();
            $('#spMsgError').hide();
            $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
        }
```

What I have so far

1. Check whether all the checkboxes are selected or not, if not highlight all - done
2. Check if any of checkboxes are not selected, highlight only unchecked checkboxes - struggling here.

Can any one shed light on how to go about point number 2.

Comment: If you're going to do something with all of them you should add a `class="error-message"` and then do `$('.error-message').show()` instead of specifying 8 ids.

Comment: @parchment.  sure will that too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : You already have jquery selector for unchecked input box which you are using to get length of all checkbox and comparing it with unchecked checkbox length :

```
if ($('input:checkbox').length == $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').length) {
```

You can use the same like below :

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').addClass("outLineRed");
```

Comment: Yeah, but you have used `:unchecked` initially and I just point it to the same code as OP using

Comment: But when you posted your answer with `:unchecked`, I started typing mine.. by the time I posted my answer you already done your editing, then how could I comment.

Answer (score 4):

Try `$('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').addClass("outLineRed");`

`$('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').addClass("outLineRed");` is also possible, but according to the [jQuery documentaion](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) its equivalent to `input[type=checkbox]`.